# Button with script send postback with values after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

**EDIT: **
I have a form with a button

```
@Html.Hidden("id", Model.DutyID)
@Html.Hidden("godzina", Model.godzina)
...
<div id="years" class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Wybierz cel spotkania</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>
...
<div id="months" class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Wybierz stopień</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>
...
<div id="days" class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Wybierz opiekuna</button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>
                </div>
...
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="confirm" type="button">Umów</button>
```

and then I have script binded with this button

```
$("#confirm").click(function () {
    var request = {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        godzina: $('#godzina').val(),
        cel: $("#years button").text(),
        stopien: $("#months button").text(),
        opiekun: $("#days button").text()
    };
    $.post("UmawianieSpotkania", request, function (response) {
    });
});
```

And the problem was...

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UmawianieSpotkania(string cel, string stopien, string opiekun, string id, DateTime godzina)
           {
                    ...
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

Problem was... My post is doing only once and take values "cel" "stopien" "opiekun" as null, but... if i clicked second or multiple times during executing first ActionResult (while looking at breakpoints), this post will execute multiple times with values i wanted to execute.

but i added type="button" thanks to @Ubiquitous Developers and now it works

but now in ActionResult(...)

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

...doesn't work

Comment: how does your HTML markup looks like , specifically the values you are using to build the request js object

Comment: This should work even the first time.

Comment: **EDIT:**
I changed button to 
`<button class="btn btn-default" id="confirm" type="button">Umów</button>`
and now my ActionResult get all values in first time, but didn't RedirectToAction
`[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UmawianieSpotkania(...)
        {
           ...
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give button type as button

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="confirm" type="button">Umów</button>
```

if you don't give type as button, it will work as a submit. so you submit form twice, by js and form

Comment: ok, after button click i have all values as i want to, but... :) in ActionResult(...)
{...
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
}
i have redirect which didn't work now. any help?

Comment: so you want to redirect to index action of the controller at the end of the UmawianieSpotkania action?

Comment: check you controller name in this RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller"). is your controller name is "Controller"?

Comment: of course not :) my Controller is named "DutyController" and in RedirectToAction i have (... , "Duty") so it should work. My "Index" in DutyController doesn't take any argument so it should work.

Comment: OK! I HAVE IT! IN SCRIPT i have to write a body of function 

`$.post("UmawianieSpotkania", request, function (response) {
            var redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Controller")';
            window.location.href = redirectUrl;
        });`

and it works now :) when the body of this function was empty, it does nothing in the end of postback. thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour, you click the button x times, you get the action called x times. You should disable the button in the OnClick handler and enable it when the post succeeds or fails.

```
$("#confirm").click(function () {
  ...

  this.prop("disabled", true);  

  $.post(...
});
```

Comment: But my problem is that i only want to execute it like on second time. this first time didn't give me expected result, because i need to have all values from form. the second time and other times is my needed result, but this first post didn't work as i want to.

Comment: @wilkuhaze Then i didn't understand your question in the first place. Please edit your question and show us more html code, especially the code including the elements you are referring to.